# Is it ok to buy non-sterile scalpels for non-medical reasons during the COVID outbreak?

Tags: covid-19, surgery

I'm working on a non-medical project.  Its only relationship to COVID is that I'm at home now and have more time to devote to it.

For this project, I need to use scalpels.  Because I'm only cutting inanimate objects, I use non-sterile ones like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DNW2D9S).  They're identical to [sterile scalpels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076R5GLGC) used in surgery, except for the fact that they're not sterile.

I know there's a shortage of certain types of medical equipment now, particularly masks and ventilators.  I haven't heard of any surgery associated with COVID, but I wanted to check first: is there any risk of running out of scalpels?  If there's a possibility that hospitals will need to buy and sterilize non-sterile scalpels for use in surgery, I definitely don't want to contribute to a shortage.

**Is it ok to buy non-sterile scalpels to use for a non-medical project, or do I risk contributing to a potential shortage of scalpels needed for urgent medical purposes?**

Comment: You deleted my comment answer yet are doing this yourself!

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yeah, you're right. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are buying in huge quantities, the likelihood to cause a shortage of any kind of medical equipment is probably low.